# Missing hover effect and ability to click on last item in header

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar, but my last link ("Contact") stopped working. It still displays, but it is not clickable, and doesn't have the hover effect. I'm not sure what I did. I'm new to this, so I probably deleted something somewhere. I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```css
.mainHeader nav ul{
  /*removes bullet points*/
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: center;
  display: inline; 
  bottom: 20px;
  font-family: Avenir;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 50px;
}

/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;

}

/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:hover {
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  height: 20px;

}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  color:000000;
  text-shadow: none; 
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
  <img src="header.jpg">

  <nav><ul>
    <!--nav bar links-->
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul></nav>
</header>
```

Comment: @Amit, here's a JSfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/dcm4fhhg/ 
Admittedly I'm having a bit of trouble discerning the problem.  Rsterling - can you post an image or something of what you wish to happen, or lay everything out for us so we know what your end goal is?

Comment: In the last part of the `css` change `color:000000;` to `color: #000000;` As Alexander mentioned, it's not apparent what the actual issue is.

Comment: .mainHeader nav ul li - float: center;  bottom: 20px;?

Comment: Here is an image that hopefully gives an example of my problem. All suggestions below haven't worked. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20325361/IMG_4797.JPG @Amit

Answer (score 0):

Contact button works for me. I have modified little bit.

```
/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px 15px;
 }

/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/xehihocuyi/2/

Answer (score 0):

Few lines of CSS code is not written properly. For example in below code you missed the `#` for color property. And float CSS property there is no any value `center`.

> Float have these properties. and `none` is initial value. Values are
>   `left, right, none, inherit;`

```
.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    color:000000;
    text-shadow: none; 
}
```

Here is the working [Demo](http://jsbin.com/zezujacugi/1/edit?html,css,output).

```css
.mainHeader nav ul{
    /*removes bullet points*/
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    float: center; /*there is no such value*/
    display: inline; 
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
}

/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
  /*  color: #FFF;*/
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;

}

/*text inside menu bar*/
.mainHeader nav a {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;

}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    color:#ef8913;
    text-shadow: none; 
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
        <img src="header.jpg">

        <nav>
          <ul>
            <!--nav bar links-->
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ks9e10e/2/)**

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#ccc;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
    /*removes bullet points*/
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
    float: center;
    display: inline;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: Avenir;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
}
/*text inside menu bar*/
 .mainHeader nav li a:link, .mainHeader nav li a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}
/*text inside menu bar*/
 .mainHeader nav li a:link, .mainHeader nav li a:hover {
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    height: 20px;
}
.mainHeader nav li a:hover, .mainHeader nav li a:active, .mainHeader nav .active li a:link, .mainHeader nav .active li a:visited {
    color:#000000;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

I added  `li` before `a` like this `.mainHeader nav li a:link, .mainHeader nav li a:visited`